# I want to put Object into Tree.dataProvider

Tags: xml, json, actionscript-3, tree

## Problem

-- I want to make hierarchical tree structure

-- got JSON data structure from PHP by API

-- tried to use "mx.controls.Tree"

-- Tree.dataProvider only accepts XML

-- parsed JSON to Object, by using JSON.decode()  [as3corelib]

-- parsed Object to XML by using SimpleXMLEncoder.encodeValue()  [mx.rpc.xml.SimpleXMLEncoder]

-- and it input to Tree.dataProvider

---

## Harm

And then, I got this view.

[Tree view screenshot](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s51/sh/cf05fcc2-8650-47ba-b95f-b16ccc021434/1e216014e2914dec3059fcf6028dac6f)

---

## Cause

Then I noticed that I should set label or something represents XML tag's attribute.

This is because of Tree.labelField="@label".

---

## Solution

Thus I thought three choices.

A. Write a method what works when parsing Object to XML, add the label attribute.

B. Write dynamic XML that have label attribute, and put Object properties to XML iteratively.

C. Write original tree method that can accept Object or JSON data directly.

---

## But

These are so tired so

D. You tell me other good solution.

is the best way I think.

How should I do, ActionScript Masters?

[Sample code](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s51/sh/d57b9882-043a-48c6-a8df-4e88b11941ec/6db8497c3b8ea3ba38317f777b4f0827) is in evernote (because copy&paste from eclipse [flash builder] is so bad in indent...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this problem and there are no answer to this problem. So I remain code for you.

```
private function onCreationComplete(event:FlexEvent):void{
    app = S4M(this.parentApplication);
    var service:HTTPService;
    loadSubsymbols();

    // *************************************************
    // generateRequest
    // *************************************************
    function loadSubsymbols():void { 
        service = new HTTPService();
        var action_url:String = "subsymbols.json";
        service.url = api_url + action_url;
        service.method = "GET";
        service.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, httpResult); 
        service.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT, httpFault);
        service.contentType = "application/json"
        service.headers = { Accept:"application/json" };
        service.send(); 
    } 
}

    // *************************************************
    // connectionSuccess 
    // *************************************************
    private function httpResult(event:ResultEvent):void {
        var json:String = event.result as String;
        var obj:Object = JSON.decode(json);
        var tree:Object = obj.tree;
        treeView.dataProvider = object2json(tree);
        //MonsterDebugger.trace(this, treeView.dataProvider);
        MonsterDebugger.trace(this, treeView.selectedItem.label);
    }

    // *************************************************
    // generateJSONfromObject
    // ************************************************* 
    private function object2json(node:Object):Object{
        var name:String = node.name;
        var children:Array = new Array();
        if(isThereChildren(node)){
            for(var child:String in node.children){
                children.push(object2json(node.children[child]));
            }
        }

        if(isThereSubsymbols(node)){
            children.push(object2json(node.subsymbols[0]));
        }

        if(doYouHaveSomething(node)){
            return {label: name, children: children}
        }else{
            return {label: name}
        }
    }

    private function isThereChildren(nd:Object):Boolean{
        return nd.children
    }

    private function isThereSubsymbols(nd:Object):Boolean{
        return nd.subsymbols
    }

    private function doYouHaveSomething(nd:Object):Boolean{
        return nd.children || nd.subsymbols
    }

    // *************************************************
    // connectionFailure
    // *************************************************
    private function httpFault(event:FaultEvent):void { 
        var faultstring:String = event.fault.faultString; 
        Alert.show(faultstring);
    }
```

1. connect JSON API
2. JSONtext to Object by as3corelib.JSON.decode
3. scan and cut Object structure by recursive method(this is little difficult)
4. create specific JSON for TreeId.dataProvider

MonsterDebugger.trace(this, something) is verrrrrrrrrrrry good.
newbie, use this.